# postgres how to add value inside array if store in json field

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-10

```
{
    "title": "new abc",
    "genres": ["Fiction", "Thriller", "Horror"],
    "published": false
}
```

Here is my JSON store inside the database.
I want to add value inside the genres field which is array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`jsonb_insert`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html) might be what you're looking for.

From the documentation

```
jsonb_insert(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb [, insert_after boolean])
```

> Returns target with new_value inserted. If target section designated
>   by path is in a JSONB array, new_value will be inserted before target
>   or after if insert_after is true (default is false). If target section
>   designated by path is in JSONB object, new_value will be inserted only
>   if target does not exist. As with the path oriented operators,
>   negative integers that appear in path count from the end of JSON
>   arrays.

This query inserts into the `genres` array a new element named `Comedy` in beginning of the array - tested on PostgreSQL 10.10:

```
SELECT jsonb_insert('{"title": "new abc",
                      "genres": ["Fiction", "Thriller", "Horror"],
                      "published": false}','{genres,0}','"Comedy"',false);

                                          jsonb_insert                                           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"title": "new abc", "genres": ["Comedy", "Fiction", "Thriller", "Horror"], "published": false}
(1 Zeile)
```

**Edit**: Checking if an element already exists inside of the array before inserting it - see comments:

Sample data

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (f jsonb);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('{"title": "new abc",
                      "genres": ["Fiction", "Thriller", "Horror"],
                      "published": false}');
```

Query - non-existing element

```
SELECT jsonb_insert(f,'{genres,0}','"Comedy"',false) 
FROM t
WHERE '"Comedy"' NOT IN 
  (SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(f#>'{genres}'));

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"title": "new abc", "genres": ["Comedy", "Fiction", "Thriller", "Horror"], "published": false}
(1 Zeile)
```

Query - existing element

```
SELECT jsonb_insert(f,'{genres,0}','"Fiction"',false) 
FROM t
WHERE '"Fiction"' NOT IN 
  (SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(f#>'{genres}'));

 jsonb_insert 
--------------
(0 Zeilen)
```

Comment: is it possible to check, the key is present or not in the json.
i.e if I want to add (serial) inside genres the is it possible to check by the query itself and add to the array element serial if not present.